# add a short delay between each iteration of do while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, delay

I have written a code to trigger click event on the four labels on my page and the loop is working fine as i tested it using alert box written in loop body. but by default, in jquery all iterations happen so quick that it is impossible to see those click events happening.

so I want to add a short delay in the do while loop. Loop that i have written is:

```
var elets = $('label');
var n = elets.length;
var i=0;
do
{
    //setTimeout ( function() {
    var forname = elets[i].getAttribute("for");
    var selected_label = $('label[for='+forname+']');
    selected_label.trigger("click");
    i++;
    //}, 3000);
} while(i<n)
```

I also want this loop to be repeated continuously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `setTimeout`. With an immediately invoked named function, the code can be about as simple and clear as with a `do` or `for` loop :

```
var elets = $('label');
var n = elets.length;
var i=0;
(function doOne(){
    var forname = elets[i].getAttribute("for");
    var selected_label = $('label[for='+forname+']');
    selected_label.trigger("click");
    if (i++<n) setTimeout(doOne);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks dystroy.. and sorry i was away, so i couldn't accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

you can also use .delay() function

refer http://api.jquery.com/delay/

for example :

```
<script>
   $( "button" ).click(function() {  
      $( "div.first").delay( 800);
   });
```

Here div first will be loade after interval of 800 milliseconds once click on button.

Comment: `delay` *can* be used, but that's not so simple. If you think you know how to do it, please add some code instead of just a link.